# 'sendmail' doesn't reliably send notification to be triggered by 'logread' output

Tags: sendmail, openwrt

I am trying to monitor the logs on my OPENWRT router and send an email when the PPPTD service writes to the log:

```
Mon Nov 29 09:10:31 2021 daemon.info pptpd[5832]: CTRL: Client x.x.x.x control connection started
```

I am using this script:

```
#!/bin/ash

logread -f | awk ' /control connection started/ { print "From: R01 Router <orignating email@email.com>"
       print "To: mypersonalemail@email.com"
       print "Mime-Version: 1.0"
       print "Content-Type: text/plain"
       print "Subject: Incoming PPTP connection from" $10
       print "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit"
       print "Incoming PPTP connection from " $10 } ' | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t &
```

but getting inconsitant results because email is not always sent.  Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

The reason why this was not working was that since the `logread -f` is *continuously monitoring the log*, the `sendmail` buffer was never being closed and therefore the mail was never being sent until the process is terminated.

```
#!/bin/ash

logread -f | awk ' /control connection started/ { 
    print "From: R01 Router <myemail@email.com>" > "awkout.txt"
    print "To: "myemail@email.com" >> "awkout.txt"
    print "Mime-Version: 1.0" >> "awkout.txt"
    print "Content-Type: text/plain" >> "awkout.txt"
    print "Subject: Incoming PPTP connection from " $10 >> "awkout.txt"
    print "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" >> "awkout.txt"
    print "Incoming PPTP connection from " $10 >> "awkout.txt"
    system("ssmtp myemail@email.com < awkout.txt");
    } ' &
```

This code will send an email everytime the awk makes a match.  Hope this helps anybody who is trying to monitor the logread under OpenWrt